# Php Session Variables ()

Tags: php, session

I have been developing a web-application and I am using a lot of session variables.I have certain doubts about using them

- 1.When N number of users loggin so N number of session variables are created.. does it affect the overall performance of the site ?
- Does using session variable pose any security issues ?
- Is there any other alternative for session varibles ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Site performance depends on how optimized your script/queries as well as your server hardware.

2 - Session variables/data is secure as long as your session.save_path (in php.ini) is outside of user access, Usually it's /tmp (on *nix servers) that's safe.

3 - You may use cookies, text files OR mysql database to manually store your data.

but sessions are always best bet to save data that you need at every call of page.

Answer (score 0):

using session is good for authentication purpose such as login in PHP.

using of session instead of variables is not a good idea...

sessions are stored on **server** and a reference to servers session id is also stored on client browser cache as sessionCookie for each time the client requests the server the session id from server and cookie are validated...

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you are storing in the variables. 
Much info could probably be stored in a database.

According to this(http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?822721-Session-variables-vs-database-storage-in-terms-of-speed) sitepoint discussion there are no real speed differences.